# Calculate avg in MongoDB with missing values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm currently developing an node application that gathers information in intervals and saves them in MongoDB. Not every data set is received for each interval run, thats why only some of the data sets will get a new entry.

I have data that is structured like so:

```
{
  dataSet1: {
    entries: [
      {run: 3, score: 5},
      {run: 4, score: 3},
      {run: 7, score: 11},
      {run: 10, score: 4},
    ]
  },
  dataSet2: {...}
}
```

I want to get the average score for each data set. The run attribute is auto incremented and indicates in which iteration the score was taken. Missing runs shall count as 0 score. I also have the information about the last run number, so there can also be 0 score values after the last entry of a data set. For example if the current run is 12 then two 0 score values for run 11 and 12 need to be additionally considered for dataSet1.

Of course I could store such missing values as 0 in MongoDB. But every run might only have few data sets to update. Updating all data sets with empty values increases storage and performance a lot.

Is there any way to let MongoDB calculate the average score considering the missing entries?

Comment: Is the last run number stored in the document?  Are the number of dataSets fixed, or variable?

Comment: Each run is stored in a separate collection, so yes the last run number is stored but in another document. The number of dataSets may vary as a new run might have a score for a new dataSet included. So dataSets only get added, no dataSet is removed.

Comment: I think the point which was being made while also asking for clarification is that unless you store the "last run" index into your summary document then you would need to query another collection to find out that number. So with that said ( and it's a good thing to do ) why not just process the average in client code "filling in the blanks"? Unless you intend to aggregate these "averages" across documents?

Comment: @user3561036: over time there will be a very large number (thousands) of runs. Processing the avg in the client means delivering all those data to the client. I could store the last run number in each dataSet if that helps calculating the avg.

Comment: @DerDree It doesn't have to. Use an aggregate to compute the sum of the scores for each dataset server-side and then divide that by the number of runs to get your average.